# Normal Bayesian Model: Marginal distribution of $\bar X$ with unknown mean and unknown variance

Tags: distributions, bayesian, normal-distribution, bayes

For $i=1, \ldots, K$ and $j=1, \ldots,n$, assume the following model.
\begin{align}
X_{ij} \mid \mu_i, \sigma^2 & \stackrel{_\text{ind}}{\sim} N(\mu_i, \sigma_i^2) \\
\mu_i & \stackrel{_\text{iid}}{\sim} N(\mu, \tau^2) \\
\ln(\sigma_i^2) & \stackrel{_\text{iid}}{\sim} N(\mu_v, \tau_v^2)
\end{align}
Is it possible to obtain the marginal distribution of $\bar X_i$ under this model? Thank you very much.

Comment: If you're not committed to a log-normal distribution for each $\sigma_i^2$ but instead go with a normal-inverse-gamma distribution for both $\mu_i, \sigma_i^2$, then each $X_{ij}$ would be marginally t-distributed, which would give you what you need

Comment: Actually, I'm having some doubts about what I just said. Say the OP does switch like I advocated and each $X_{ij}$ are now t-distributed. Is it true that the distribution of $\bar X_i$ would be given? The sum of two independent t-distributed R.V.s is not necessarily a t-distributed R.V...

Comment: @Matthew why would the $t$'s be independent?